# Array filled in dispatch queue but when I try and use contents in method its empty

Tags: swift

I have pulled JSON data from an API and decoded using the JSON decoder.I have then tried to populate my array data structure with the JSON data in the dispatch queue so I can use it in other methods but when I try to access the data in other methods or functions it states the array is empty

This is how I have decoded the JSON data and tried filling the array in the dispatch queue

```
 if let url = URL(string:"https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/restaurants"){
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("app id", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
            request.setValue("REST API key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, err) in
                guard let jsonData = data else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let restaurantList = try decoder.decode(restaurants.self, from: jsonData)
                    self.restaurantStruct = restaurantList
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.fillArray()
                    }
                }
                catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Error decoding JSON", jsonErr)
                }
            }
            .resume()
        }
```

This is the fillArray method I wrote

```
 func fillArray(){
        var counter = 0
        for anitem in restaurantStruct!.results{
            //print("\(counter) : \(anitem)")
            restaurantArray.insert(["restaurant" : anitem.restaurant, "name" : anitem.name, "description" : anitem.description , "calories" : anitem.calories , "price" : anitem.price , "ImageUrl" : anitem.ImageUrl , "type" : anitem.type], at: counter)
           
            counter += 1
        }
    }
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if(collectionView == categoryCollectionView){
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
            cell.label.text = categories[indexPath.row]["Category"]
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:categories[indexPath.row]["Image"]!)
            return cell
        }
       
        else{
            let menu = getRestaurantMenu("TFC")
            print(menu)
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell2", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    
           
            return cell
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Why not fill `restaurantArray` directly in the closure instead of going via `self.restaurantStruct`? Unrelated but why use a dictionary instead of your decoded type in the array?

Comment: what do you mean by fill directly , I don't get it @JoakimDanielson

Comment: The code above doesn't look sufficient to understand the problem: you are asking the `filterArray()` function to update based on `restaurantStruct.results`, but when is it updated? Are we sure that the code is updating the `results` variable inside the `restaurantList` instance?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `fillArray`, make sure it actually runs. Put a breakpoint on `.insert`. Make sure it actually runs. Put a breakpoint on `self.restaurantStruct = restaurantList`. Make sure that actually runs. I strongly suspect one of them does not.

Comment: Do note that without locking, it is not valid to write to a property on one thread and read it on another (i.e. what you're doing with `restaurantStruct`). That is probably not your problem here, but it is dangerous, and can eventually crash on you. Instead, you would pass `restaurantList` directly to `fillArray` as a parameter and not use a property to pass the data. (But I strongly expect that your real bug is that the code you expect to run does not run, or runs in an order you do no expect. Use a debugger or print statements to debug that)

Comment: @HunterLion Yes it does update,  I have checked with a print statement that the restauarntList variables isn't empty and has the json data

Comment: I meant skip the DispatchQueue.main.async part and do everything in the closure instead.

Comment: @RobNapier I have checked previously that if the code runs with breakpoints and all the code you stated were executed, that's why I am very confused on what the issue is

Comment: @JoakimDanielson didnt make a difference

Comment: It sounds like an async ordering problem, where the array access occurs before the completion handler is executed... or possibly that you're actually modifying a copy.  More context is needed to know.  Put breakpoints on *both* the line where you expect the array to be populated *and* on the call to `fillArray` to see which one is triggered first.

Comment: Agreed w/ Chip. If the data is not there, then either you are not adding it, or you are looking at it before it's added, or you are looking at the wrong thing (for example, if you are inspecting the wrong instance of the class). Adding print statements at each step, and ensuring they all execute in the order you expect (and ensuring they are all executed on the object you expect) will show you where your mistake is.

Comment: @ChipJarred I hv seen issue the the `getRestaurant()` method is being called before the `fillArray()` method is called in the async. Why would that happen? if the async is in the viewdidload and viewdidload is the first thing that is called

Comment: @GggGgff the completion handler for `session.dataTask` will be *scheduled* to run whenever the network access completes.  It does not wait. So `viewDidLoad` will complete and then some time later, the completion handler will run filling the array.  In your completion handler you need to tell the view to update, possibly doing other things in your ViewController first.  Remember to do that on `DispatchQueue.main` since your completion handler might not be executed on `main`.

Comment: Since you're calling `fillArray` on `DispatchQueue.main`, it might as simple as adding `yourView.setNeedsDisplay()` to the end of `fillArray`.

Comment: @ChipJarred what would that do, would that ensure everything in the viewdidload executes before proceeding with the other stuff

Comment: No.  You don't want to block `viewDidLoad` on a network access.  That would make your app unresponsive until the access completes.  What it would do is once you have the data, is inform the view to redraw itself on the next main run loop iteration.  If your ViewController executes other code after the `dataTask` to set up data in the view, you'll need to call that code, which might mean extracting it into a separate method.

Comment: If there's a significant delay between calling `dataTask` and your completion handler, you might want to display an activity indicator to tell the user that the view is busy, but you don't want to block.

Comment: BTW - if you do try to block `viewDidLoad`, for example using a `DispatchSemaphore`, you'll probably find that your app freezes.  It's common for Cocoa/CocoaTouch to schedule completion handlers on `DispatchQueue.main`, which is the same queue where `viewDidLoad` is called.  So blocking `viewDidLoad` prevents the handler from ever executing.  Even if `dataTask` does schedule its completion handler on a different queue, you're explicitly calling `fillArray` on `main`, so the completion handler might run, but`fillArray` wouldn't.  Don't ever block `DispatchQueue.main`.

Comment: @ChipJarred I have added the `yourView.setNeedsDisplay()` to the end of the `fillArray` method doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: @GggGgff, First, do you know for sure that your view works?  I mean, if you don't call `dataTask`, but instead populate the array with some local static data, does the view display that data?  If not, get that working first.  Once that works, re-enable the call to `dataTask`.  Does the view work now?  If not, then look at the code that `viewDidLoad` calls after `dataTask`.  Does any involve setting data in the view, subviews, or any of their delegates?  If so, extract that into a method, and call it in your `dataTask` completion handler.

Comment: Since your code involves a `UICollectionView`, you might need to call its `reloadData()` method in your `dataTask` completion handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't (yet) have a solution, but after discussion in comments, I thought it would be helpful to provide some code that might help in the debugging process, and comments are too limited for that.

First you need to determine if your collection view is even working as you expect.  To determine that we'll need some local data, add these to your `ViewController` source file.  They can be globals

```swift
// debugRestuarantsJSON should be exactly the same format you're 
// expecting from your REST call.
fileprivate let debugRestaurantsJSON = "Paste valid restaurants JSON text here"
fileprivate let debugRestaurantsData = debugRestaurantsJSON.data(using: .utf8)
```

Then let's extract the bulk of your `dataTask` completion handler into it's own method so we can use it for the debugging data:

```swift
private func setRestaurantData(from restaurantJSONData: Data?)
{
    guard let jsonData = restaurantJSONData else { return }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let restaurantList = try decoder.decode(restaurants.self, from: jsonData)
        self.restaurantStruct = restaurantList
        self.fillArray()
    }
    catch let jsonErr {
      print("Error decoding JSON", jsonErr)
    }
}
```

Note that I removed `DispatchQueue.main.async` from the call to `fillArray()`, so if you altered `fillArray` to make UI calls, such as the one I suggested in comments to call `setNeedsDisplay()`, remove those.

And let's wrap your `dataTask` call inside a method too:

```swift
private func requestRestaurantData(from urlString: String)
{
    if let url = URL(string: urlString)
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("app id", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
        request.setValue("REST API key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request)
        { (data, response, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("URL request failed: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else { self.setRestaurantData(from: data) }
        }
        .resume()
     }
}
```

I added a check for the case when `err` is not `nil` to handle network/HTTP errors, and it expects the URL as a `String` parameter.  It also uses the `setRestuarantData(from:)` method we created earlier.  Otherwise it's the same as your code.

Instead of calling `requestRestaurantData(from:)` directly where you originally called your `dataTask` in your code, let's provide one more level of indirection:

```swift
enum RestaurantRequestType {
    case normal, debugSync, debugAsync
}

func requestRestaurantData(_ requestType: RestaurantRequestType = .normal)
{
    switch requestType
    {
        case .normal:
            requestRestaurantData(
                from: "https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/restaurants"
            )
            
        case .debugSync:
            setRestaurantData(from: debugRestaurantsData)
            
        case .debugAsync:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setRestaurantData(from: debugRestaurantsData)
            }
    }
}
```

Now in your code where you originally called `dataTask`, replace it with

```swift
    requestRestaurantData(.normal)
```

That should give exactly the same behavior you already have.  Just make sure you didn't break anything in making those changes.  In other words, your `UICollectionView` will still not contain the restaurant data.  That's to be expected, but everything else that was working before should still work.

Then change from `.normal` to `.debugSync`.  That will synchronously fill the array before `requestRestaurantData(_:)` returns.  If the only problem is setting the view's data from an asynchronous task, your view should now display the debug data.  If it doesn't, you're fundamentally not setting up the view or its data correctly, and that has to be fixed before proceeding.

Let's assume that your view does show the debug data.  Now change from `.debugSync` to `.debugAsync`.  That will fill the array in an asynchronous task, so it will behave more like `dataTask`, but without the network access.  It will also have a shorter latency, because it won't need to wait for network response.  It'll just execute in one of the next few iterations of the main runloop, probably on the very next one if no other tasks are queued up.

If your view isn't updated using `.debugAsync`, which I suspect will be the case, you know that you're not informing the view, its delegate, or since it's a `UICollectionView`, its `dataSource` that there's new data, so it needs to update/redraw.  My current thought is that is you'll need to call the `reloadData` method for your `UICollectionView`:

```swift
private func setRestaurantData(from restaurantJSONData: Data?)
{
    guard let jsonData = restaurantJSONData else { return }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let restaurantList = try decoder.decode(restaurants.self, from: jsonData)
        self.restaurantStruct = restaurantList
        self.fillArray()
       
        // ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE - replace yourUICollectionView appropriately
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.yourUICollectionView.reloadData() }
    }
    catch let jsonErr {
      print("Error decoding JSON", jsonErr)
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, then there will be more debugging to do.  Comment to let me know.

Eventually when you get that working, change from `.debugAsync` to `.normal`.  Assuming network connectivity and the server is running, your view should work.  If not, there is some completely different problem than I'm thinking of.  But I'm pretty sure that if it works with `.debugAsync` it will work with `.normal`.

Once you get it working, you can remove the debugging code.  I would leave the non-debugging extracted methods in place though.